# When I resize the window, a brand new blank space appears before my footer and I can't figure out why

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If you download and run the code below, you'll perceive when you resize your window to a width below 768px, and then to a greater width, a brand new blank space will appear between the last section and the footer. I surely don't want that happening and I'm trying do figure out its reason, but I don't have any clue about what's leading to it.

The only circumstance the blank keeps from appearing is when I delete the footer, but this seems like a misleading clue.

What should I do?

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  --prim-blue: #005aa6;
  --sec-blue: #7facd2;
  --prim-yellow: #ffbc00;
  --sec-yellow: #ffdd7f;
  --prim-gray: #CCCCCC;
  --sec-gray: #333333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
a,
li,
input {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h5,
h6,
p,
a,
li,
input {
  font-size: 18px
}

h6 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

.side-limits {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

nav .col-12 {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #0002;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav a,
nav button {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

nav input {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-margin {
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
}

nav img {
  height: 28px;
}

.nav-container-responsive a,
.nav-container-responsive button,
.nav-container-responsive form {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-container-responsive button {
  margin: auto;
}

.nav-container-responsive form button {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-container-responsive form {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.nav-container button {
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-container button,
.nav-container form,
.nav-container .a-nav-item,
.nav-container .dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.nav-container a img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-resp-icon {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 16px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content {

}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: var(--prim-blue);
}

.destaque {
  margin: 16px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 8px #0004;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.destaque:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 8px #0008;
}

.destaque-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #000A;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
}

.destaque:hover .destaque-overlay {
  background-color: #0007;
}

.destaque img {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


.destaque-content-container {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.destaque h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.destaque a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.destaque .tag {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.destaque a:hover h3,
.destaque a.tag:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.destaque p.meta {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.destaque p.meta a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.destaque p.meta a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.sobre-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.sobre-logo {
  width: 100%;
}

.sobre-logo img {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto 18px;

}

.sobre-texto {
  width: 100%;
}

.sobre-texto p {
  margin: 18px 0 0;
}

.mais {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

.mais a {
  background-color: var(--prim-blue);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;

}

.mais a:hover {
  background-color: var(--sec-blue);
}

a.mais:hover {
  background-color: var(--sec-blue);
}

.post-container {
  display: block;
}


.post-card {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #0002;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 24px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.post-card-content {
  padding: 24px 24px 30px;
}

.post-card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #0006;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.post-card a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.post-card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.post-card a img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0;
}

.post-card h3 {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.post-card p {
  margin: 8px 0 16px;
}

.post-card a h3:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.post-card a.tag {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: var(--prim-blue);
}

.post-card a.tag:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.post-card p.meta a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.post-card p.meta a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.post-card a.pl-author {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.post-card a.pl-author:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.blog-post p.meta {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.pl-post p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.informativo ul li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.informativo ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.network-card {

}

footer .footer-container {
  margin-top: 48px;
  background-color: var(--sec-gray);
  padding: 40px 0 32px;
}

footer p,
footer a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  margin: 8px auto;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer-logo a {
  width: 256px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.footer-logo a img {
  width: 256px;
}

footer .social-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 32px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

footer .social-container img {
  width: 24px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

footer li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

footer .footer-bottom-container {
  margin-top: 32px;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;   }
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;  }
  .col-3 {width: 25%;     }
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;  }
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;  }
  .col-6 {width: 50%;     }
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;  }
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;  }
  .col-9 {width: 75%;     }
  .col-11 {width: 83.33%; }
  .col-10 {width: 91.66%; }
  .col-12 {width: 100%;   }

  .nav-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  nav a,
  nav button {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .nav-container button,
  .nav-container form,
  .nav-container .a-nav-item,
  .nav-container .dropdown {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav-container a img {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .nav-container img {
    height: 28px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }

  .nav-container form {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .nav-container input {
    max-width: 183px;
  }

  .nav-container a.navbar-resp-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-container form button {
    display: inline;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown button::after {
    content: " \025BE";
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 180px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #DDD;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    font-style: normal;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  .destaque {
    height: 360px;
  }

  .destaque-content-container {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 24px 0 24px 24px;
  }

  .sobre-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 18px 0 36px;
  }

  .sobre-logo {
    width: 40%;
  }

  .sobre-logo img {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .sobre-texto {
    width: 60%;
  }

  .sobre-texto p {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .post-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  }

  .post-card {
    width: 49%
  }

  footer .social-container {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Observatório do Empreendedor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;1,300;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--Menu responsivo -->
    <script>
    function respFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("navBar");
        if (x.className === "nav-container") {
          x.className += "-responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "nav-container";
        }
      }

    </script>



  </head>

  <body>


    <nav>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="side-limits">
          <div id="navBar" class="nav-container">
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/logo_neg.png" alt=""> </a>
            <a href="#" class="a-nav-item">Blog</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button type="button" name="button">Lente do Observatório</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Projetos Legislativos</a>
                <a href="#">Parlamentares</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-nav-item">Manual do Empreendedor</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button type="button" name="button">Projetos</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Eventos</a>
                <a href="#">Cursos</a>
                <a href="#">Reforma Tributária</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button type="button" name="button">Sobre</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Institucional</a>
                <a href="#">Contato</a>
                <a href="#">Informativo</a>
                <a href="#">Linha Editorial</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Pesquisar">
              <button type="button" name="button">Ir</button>
            </form>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-resp-icon" onclick="respFunction()">&#9776;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="nav-margin">
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--DESTAQUE-->
    <section>
      <div class="side-limits">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="destaque">

            <div class="destaque-overlay">
            </div>

            <img src="assets/fpolis.jpg" alt="">

            <div class="destaque-content-container">
              <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>
              <a href="#"><h3>Como escrever um título realmente longo</h3></a>
              <a href="#"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p></a>
              <p class="meta">Por <a href="#">Fulano de tal</a> em <a href="#">5/4/1984</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </section>

    <!--SOBRE-->
    <section>
      <div id="sobre" class="side-limits">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2>Sobre nós</h2>
          <div class="sobre-container">
            <div class="sobre-logo">
              <img src="assets/logo_neg.png" alt="">

            </div>
            <div class="sobre-texto">
              <p>O <strong>Observatório do Empreendedor</strong> é uma organização privada, apartidária e sem fins lucrativos que visa melhorar o ambiente de negócios no Brasil por meio do aprimoramento regulatório e da educação.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
            <div class="mais">
              <a href="#">Saiba mais</a>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>



    <!--BLOG-->
    <section>
      <div id="blog"  class="side-limits">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2>Blog</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

          <div class="post-container">

            <div class="post-card blog-post">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/fpolis.jpg" alt="">
              </a>

              <div class="post-card-content">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>

                <a href="#">
                  <h3>O que o Crocs™ tem a dizer sobre a tributação no Brasil?</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </a>
                <p class="meta">Por <a href="#">Fulano de tal</a> em <a href="#">5/4/1984</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post-card blog-post">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/fpolis.jpg" alt="">
              </a>

              <div class="post-card-content">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>

                <a href="#">
                  <h3>O que o Crocs™ tem a dizer sobre a tributação no Brasil?</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </a>
                <p class="meta">Por <a href="#">Fulano de tal</a> em <a href="#">5/4/1984</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post-card blog-post">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/fpolis.jpg" alt="">
              </a>

              <div class="post-card-content">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>

                <a href="#">
                  <h3>O que o Crocs™ tem a dizer sobre a tributação no Brasil?</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </a>
                <p class="meta">Por <a href="#">Fulano de tal</a> em <a href="#">5/4/1984</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post-card blog-post">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="assets/fpolis.jpg" alt="">
              </a>

              <div class="post-card-content">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>

                <a href="#">
                  <h3>O que o Crocs™ tem a dizer sobre a tributação no Brasil?</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </a>
                <p class="meta">Por <a href="#">Fulano de tal</a> em <a href="#">5/4/1984</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="mais">
              <a href="#">Veja mais</a>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <!--LENTE DO OBSERVATÓRIO-->
    <section>
      <div id="lente" class="side-limits">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2>Lente do Observatório</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

          <div class="post-container">

            <div class="post-card pl-post">
              <div class="post-card-content">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>
                <a href="#">
                  <h3>PL 1.000/2021</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="pl-author"><strong>Autor do Projeto</strong> (Partido/UF) </a>

                <a href="#">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="post-card pl-post">
              <div class="post-card-content">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tópico do texto</a>
                <a href="#">
                  <h3>PL 1.000/2021</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="pl-author"><strong>Autor do Projeto</strong> (Partido/UF) </a>

                <a href="#">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                </a>

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>



          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="mais">
              <a href="#">Veja mais</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <!--INFORMATIVO-->
    <section>
      <div id="informativo" class="side-limits">
        <div class="col-12 informativo">
          <h2>Informativo</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Realizada a Assembleia Geral Ordinária (AGO) de Janeiro de 2021</a>
              <p>A pauta da AGO foi exclusivamente para deliberar a respeito das contas do Observatório do Empreendedor do exercício de 2020.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Observatório do Empreendedor realiza a Assembleia Geral Ordinária e Extraordinária</a>
              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a>
              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="mais">
              <a href="#">Veja mais</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--FOOTER-->
    <footer>
      <div class="col-12 footer-container">
        <div class="side-limits">

          <div class="footer-logo">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="assets/oemporgbr.png" alt="" class="footer-logo">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="social-container">
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/social/fb.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/social/ig.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/social/li.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/social/tt.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Eventos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pesquisar</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lente do Observatório</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Manual do Empreendedor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reforma Tributária</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Institucional</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Linha Editorial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Prestação de Contas</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Associe-se</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Doe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Informativo</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="col-12 footer-bottom-container">

            <p><strong>Observatório do Empreendedor</strong></p>
            <p><a href="#">Termos de uso</a> &#8226; <a href="#">Política de privacidade</a></p>
            <p>CNPJ: 36.535.282/0001-79</p>
            <p>2021. Todos direitos reservados.</p>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I went ahead and made a codepen.
https://codepen.io/FullstakBV/pen/xxReRWQ

It's easier to debug. But i don't see the problem to be honest..

Comment: Agreed. I ran the code and don't see the "space" you talk of when resizing the viewport below 768px and back up again.

Comment: Hey, guys! Thank you so much for taking a look. It seems it only happens when I'm using Firefox and when dragging the window to one of the edges (that feature available since Windows 7). Here's how it appears: https://imgur.com/a/UYIHXPi